# xamarin mysql command show Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: mysql, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to insert data into mysql database.

I'm using **mysqlConnector.**

But after I confirm insertion with my code.

Debugger returns **Index was outside the bounds of the array**

Here is my code of insertion:

```
if (co.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO inventory (flItem) VALUES('" + ItemName.Text + "');";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, co.connection);
            //MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            await DisplayAlert("TEST", cmd.CommandText, "OK");
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new AppShell());
        }
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: which specific line throws the exception, and what does the stack trace show?

Comment: I think it's at Navigation.PushAsync(new AppShell()).

Comment: that has nothing to do with MySQL.  Where is this code located?  Why are you trying to navigate to AppShell?  That is not a page you navigate TO, it represents the overall layout of your app navigation

Comment: I was wrong with it. Sorry. The sql is good, the exception showed up when at Navigation.PushAsync(new AppShell()). What I want to do is, Navigate back to main page when I finish insertion.

Comment: if you navigated to the current page with `PushAsync`, then you navigate **back** with `PopAsync`

Comment: Got it. Thanks I will try it now. Thanks for the help.